# JSF tag not found

Tags: jsf, jstl, tags, translate

I use JSF-facelets.jar 1.1.14 (I downloaded it [here](https://facelets.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=3635&expandFolder=3635&folderID=0)) and tomcat 6.0

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Created-By: 1.5.0_12-b04 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Version: 1.1.14
```

If I understand well, JSF-facelets.jar = JSF + JSTL + Facelets (???)

---

My problem is when I use "fmt" fonction.


This code...

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt">
       <h:outputLabel value="hello" />
       <fmt:formatDate value="${myBean.date}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
  </html>
```

...generate this HTML code:

```
  <html>
        <p>hello</p>
        <fmt:formatDate value="${myBean.date}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
  </html>
```

**Why "fmt:formatDate" is not change into HTML code ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to achieve this in JSF is to use converters. Use the `<h:outputText>` tag like so:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

You'll find that not all JSTL tags are supported in JSF. Facelets does provide limited support for the core tag library (`forEach`, etc) but they might not work the way you expect them to. This article provides a good summary: http://drewdev.blogspot.com/2008/03/build-time-vs-render-time.html

Comment: harto, thank you very much for this answer who work.
Moreover your link is very usefull !

Answer (score 0):

that's a jstl tag.  it doesn't need to be translated.  it's compiled from a jsp into a servlet.

what did you expect it to be "translated" into?

Comment: I have edit my question. Maybe you will understand it better.

I suppose that <fmt:formatDate value="${myBean.date}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/> should generate this HTML code "<p>24/08/2009</p>".

Not in my case, and it's the problem!
<fmt:formatDate value="${myBean.date}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/> generate this HTML code :
<fmt:formatDate value="${myBean.date}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>